# Expectations exception fails in test but not in debug with PestPHP Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-pest

I can't do a test to verify that a series of errors in the work of a job throws a series of exceptions.

The Job calls an Action which makes a call to an API.

The test makes a fake of said call emulating a 500 error.

```php
it('CallAnalyzerAction throws a communication error with slim', function () {
    $commandCenter = CommandCenter::factory()->create();
    $job_time = Carbon::now();
    $delayed_at = Carbon::now();
    $ulid = generateUlid();

    Http::fake(['*' => Http::response('Error', 500)]);

    AnalyzerCallJobV1::dispatch(
        $ulid,
        $commandCenter,
        $job_time,
        $delayed_at
    );

    $this->expectException(CallSlimException::class);
});
```

### Action called

`AnalyzerCallJobV1` handles call to an Action Class.

```php
public function handle(): void
    {
        try {
            CallAnalyzerAction::run(
                $this->ulid,
                $this->commandCenter,
                $this->job_time,
                $this->initial_delayed_at,
                $this->debug,
                false,
                $this->tries,
                $this->attempts(),
                $this->key_multiple
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->handleException($e);
        }
    }
```

In this action there a piece of code is tested, if the response of a call external API gets an error on the HTTP client, `serverErrror`

```php
if ($response->serverError()) {
   ray('Error 500');
   throw new CallSlimException("SLIM server error {$response->status()} $msg");
}
```

When I ran the test the answer was correct in the sense that the code hit the exception, since Ray shows me the message "Error 500"

However, the expectation fails.

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "App\Exceptions\CallSlimException" is thrown.
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:176
```

I'm lost with this problem

Comment: The assertion of the exception been thrown should be before the call to `dispach`, as when the exception is thrown, even the test stops, so you must tell the test that it should expect that exception and mark the test as passed when it sees the exception (hence the assertion). Can you move it before the call and share if you have the same issue?